# SQL Index - are both statements going to do the same?

Tags: sql, t-sql, indexing

I was wondering if in SQL server these two statements to create a non-clustered index will have the same behavior?

```
create nonclustered index EmpLastname_Incl_Firstname 
on employee(lastname) include (firstname);

create nonclustered index EmpLastnameFirstname 
on employee(lastname, firstname)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The key columns are optimized for things like filtering and grouping, while the included columns are optimized for retrieval of the column only. So if a lot of your queries look like the following:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname
FROM mytable
WHERE lastname = 'Doe' AND firstname = 'John'
```

then the second index you showed would be preferred. If you only use `lastname` in your `SELECT` such as the following query:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname
FROM mytable
WHERE lastname = 'Doe'
```

Then the first query would be preferred.

If you have a mix of both queries you should take the second index only as the second query is also able to make use of the first index.

Comment: `"then the first index you showed would be preferred"` : This is not correct! Your first query filter by lastname and by firstname which mean it needs to use index which is done on both columns = meaning the second index is preferred `on employee(lastname,firstname)`.

Comment: @RonenAriely excuse me. I had the order of queries wrong in my post. I'll edit accordingly

Comment: This make sense

Answer (score 1):

absolutely no

INCLUDE means that the data from the column is stored in the index but it is not part of the index sorting

Answer (score 1):

Those statements will not have the same behavior. The index with the include will only allow key lookups on the lastname field, while the index without the include will allow key lookups on both the lastname and firstname fields. [Microsoft documentation for indexes with includes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-indexes-with-included-columns?view=sql-server-2017). This bit is especially important to your question:

> Redesign nonclustered indexes with a large index key size so that only columns used for searching and lookups are key columns. Make all other columns that cover the query into nonkey columns. In this way, you will have all columns needed to cover the query, but the index key itself is small and efficient.

If you ever need to search by the firstname field, your index should include it as a key lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Adding columns to `include` will store the respective data only on the leaf-node level of the b-tree (not in the tree itself).

Almost everything that can be accomplished with `include` can also be accomplished by putting the respective columns in the key part of the index. The exceptions are related to the length limits of the key. In doubt, it might be best to leave it in the key columns.

Having that said, there are some benefits when putting a column in `include` rather than the key part:

- the resulting index is **slightly** smaller (a few percent)
- The tree of the index might be a one level smaller
- It is documented what the column of that index is used for. That makes extending this index more easy in the future.

I find the last one the most important one.

Have a look at my recent article about this topic for a better understanding: 
https://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2019-04/include-columns-in-btree-indexes